# Explanation needed: virtual, override and base

Tags: c#, overriding, virtual, radix

Why doesn't the ", Second ID: " string in O.W2() get printed out? I know that the D2 property is empty.

```
using System;

public class O
{
    public string F { get; set; }
    public string L { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }

    public virtual string W()
    {
        return this.W2();
    }

    public virtual string W2()
    {
        return string.Format("First Name : {0}, Last name: {1}, ID: {2}", F, L, D);
    }
}

public class S : O
{
    public string D2 { get; set; }

    public override string W()
    {
        return base.W2();
    }

    public override string W2()
    {
        return base.W2() + string.Format(", Second ID: {0}", this.D2);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        O o = new S();

        o.D = "12345678";
        o.F = "John";
        o.L = "Jones";

        Console.WriteLine(o.W());

        // Output: First Name : John, Last name: Jones, ID: 12345678
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you called `override W()` which in turn calls `base.W2()`. Inside the class, `base.W2()` is determined statically (at compile time) to be the one in the base class:

```
public override string W()
{
    // directly calls W2() from the base class, ignores the override
    return base.W2(); 
}
```

If you want polymorphism for this scenario, you should omit `base` and just call `W2()`:

```
public override string W()
{
    // goes to the override
    return W2(); 
}
```

Comment: It's was just a task in school, and i didn't understand it. The + (plus) confused me, why is it ignored? So that only the `base.W2()` gets outputed and not `+ string.Format(", Second ID: {0}", this.D2)` as well?

Comment: The `+` is not ignored. The problem is that the method `override string W2()` is never called. Only the *base* method `virtual string W2()` is called, and it's called from `override string W()`, which is called from `void Main()`. If you change `override string W()` to just `return W2()` (instead of `return base.W2()`), I think it would print what you expect.

Comment: @Theodoros: You should maybe edit your answer to include code that would give the expected behavour? It would make the answer much clearer.

Comment: Oh my... Of course the method `override string W2()` is never called. No idea how i haven't seen it. Thanks! It's all clear now.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Sure! I just did.

Comment: Didn't knew that the method `override string W2()` doesn't get called if it includes the base.W2().If it works like this,then it's all clear now. Thanks! - I wanted to edit my comment above, but the edit time passed already. :(

Comment: Because in the first example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx `Employee ID: ` gets printed out.

Answer (score 0):

The function W2() in the S object is never called!!

Bec when you called W() in S object u made it call the base W2()

Try  like this:

```
public override string W()
{
    String x = base.W2();
    x = x + this.W2();
    return x;
}
```